# Spring + RabbitMQ: Tracking progress of a big task

Tags: rabbitmq, job-scheduling, spring-amqp

I'm using Spring MVC 3.2 and RabbitMQ to process data asynchronously for a web app. By using a message queue, the tasks can be easily executed in the background.

However, I started wondering what would be the best way to keep track of the progress of a big job and the overall approach to such a problem.

Without RabbitMQ it might be so easy as to create a new thread and communicate with that, but RabbitMQ adds extra complexity.

Any advice on the best architecture would be appreciated.

A job could be something like "download the photographs for 10.000 products and refresh caches". I'd like to be able to show the user a percentage of the progress in real-time.

Comment: I don't understand exactly the problem. 
One question:
The module that executes the long job is in your web-server or is it another module ?

 
You can create a thread once the consumer get a message, and then send the progress using web-socket for example.

Comment: I think I should better look at Spring Batch for a better solution and dont use Rabbit MQ for this kind of use.

Comment: Yes, it could be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use some key-value storage and update key associated with task with the progress. Quick and dirty but works in most cases and easy to implement.